# Error when import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_sliders/sliders.dart';

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I got an error when debug:

/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/media_query.dart:1358:17: Error: The type '_MediaQueryAspect' is not exhaustively matched by the switch cases since it doesn't match '_MediaQueryAspect.textScalar'.

- '_MediaQueryAspect' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/media_query.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/media_query.dart').
  Try adding a default case or cases that match '_MediaQueryAspect.textScalar'.
  switch (dependency) {
  ^
  ../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/syncfusion_flutter_sliders-23.2.6/lib/src/slider_base.dart:540:21: Error: The getter 'textScaler' isn't defined for the class 'TextPainter'.
- 'TextPainter' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/text_painter.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_painter.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'textScaler'.

Comment: try to upgrade your package.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a previous version of the same Pacakge.
For now I have checked **syncfusion_flutter_sliders: 23.1.43** is working fine.

If this version fulfilled your requirements.